# Не могу понять, в чём проблема в программе на Pascal

Tags: циклы, pascal, отладка

По заданию нужно составить процедуру определения максимального значения и его адреса в одномерном массиве. С помощью этой процедуры найти максимальные элементы в строках произвольно заданного двумерного массива и среди них найти максимальный, вывести номер строки, содержащей этот элемент.

Я всё сделал, но остаётся проблема в строках 44-45. Вроде как цикл проходит значения от 1 до Nmax, но такое чувство, что на самом деле цикл присваивает переменной i значение 1, выполняется процедура, после чего цикл завершается (не переходит на i=2 и дальше). Такие выводы я сделал из того, что после запуска программы я получаю примерно следующее содержимое в массивах arrOfMax, arrOfIndex: (5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0). То есть получаю какое-либо число в первой ячейке массивов, но остальные остаются нулевыми. Подскажите, в чём проблема? Я пробовал ради интереса выполнять вызов процедуры не через цикл, а "в тупую", вот так:

```
findMaxAndIndex(matr[1], arrOfMax[1], arrOfIndex[1]);
findMaxAndIndex(matr[2], arrOfMax[2], arrOfIndex[2]);
findMaxAndIndex(matr[3], arrOfMax[3], arrOfIndex[3]);
```

и т.д. - и в итоге получал то, что и ожидал изначально от программы (не было в массивах нулей). Пробовал вместо for использовать тот же while - проблема не исчезла. Может кто-нибудь объяснить, что я делаю не так? Обычно в Pascal не пишу, и мыслей никаких нет. Потратил часа 3 на поиск ответа, безуспешно.

Сам исходный код:

```
    program lab20;
    const
        Nmax = 10;
    type
        arra = array [1 .. Nmax] of integer;
        mtri = array [1 .. Nmax] of arra;
    var
        arrOfMax, arrOfIndex: arra;
        matr: mtri;
        maxOfMatr, i, j: integer;
    {max и index передаём по ссылке, arr - по константной ссылке}
    procedure findMaxAndIndex(const arr: arra; var max, index: integer);
    begin
        max := arr[1];
        for i := 2 to Nmax do
        begin
            if max < arr[i] then
            begin
                max := arr[i];
                index := i;
            end;
        end;
    end;
    begin
        {Заполняем двумерный массив}
        Randomize; 
        for i := 1 to Nmax do
        begin
            for j := 1 to Nmax do
            matr[i, j] := random(50);
        end;
        {Выводим двумерный массив}
        for i := 1 to Nmax do
        begin
            for j := 1 to Nmax do
            begin
                Write(matr[i, j], ' ');
            end;
            Writeln;
        end;
        {Для каждой строки найдём максимальный элемент и соответствующий индекс}
        {Занесём максимальные элементы в отдельный массив arrOfMax}
        {А соответствующие индексы в отдельный массив arrOfIndex}
        for i := 1 to Nmax do
            findMaxAndIndex(matr[i], arrOfMax[i], arrOfIndex[i]);
        {Выводим arrOfMax}
        Writeln('Массив arrOfMax:');
        for i := 1 to Nmax do
            Write(arrOfMax[i], ' ');
        Writeln;
        {Выводим arrOfIndex}
        Writeln('Массив arrOfIndex:');
        for i := 1 to Nmax do
            Write(arrOfIndex[i], ' ');
        Writeln;
        {Находим максимальный элемент матрицы}
        maxOfMatr := arrOfMax[1];
        for i := 2 to Nmax do
        begin
            if maxOfMatr < arrOfMax[i] then
                maxOfMatr := arrOfMax[i];
        end;
        {Выводим максимальный элемент}
        Write('Максимальный элемент матрицы: ', maxOfMatr);
    end.
```

Comment: А в строке, где вы объявляете процедуру `findMaxAndIndex` у вас в качестве аргумента принимается константа `arr` типа `arra` - кажется, здесь опечатка и должно быть `arr: array`

Comment: Здравствуйте! Нет, там ошибки нет - я объявлял тип "arra", который означает array [1 .. Nmax] of integer.

Comment: Точно! Извиняюсь, не заметил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Добавьте одну строчку](https://ideone.com/o6k3YH) в `findMaxAndIndex`:

```
procedure findMaxAndIndex(const arr: arra; var max, index: integer);
var i : integer;
begin
    max := arr[1];
    for i := 2 to Nmax do
```

Понятно, зачем? Или надо пояснить? :)

P.S. Как вы отлаживаетесь? ведь достаточно только две строки с отладочным выводом в цикле — до и после вызова процедуры, чтоб понять, в чем проблема... В коде по ссылке они показаны, это живой рабочий пример отладки (ну нет у меня на машине Паскаля)...

Comment: Это гениально! Большое спасибо!)) Не привык к синтаксису Паскаля, и не мог понять, в чём проблема. Теперь дошло)) Только объявление нужно вставить до begin, правильно? 

И насчёт отладки - да, это очень сильно бы помогло, но никак не скачаю IDE для Паскаля)) Обычно на этом языке ничего не пишу

Comment: Ну, я с Паскалем много работал лет 25 назад, так что забыл основательно, и могу и не туда строку воткнуть... Но поскольку онлайн-компилятор пропустил, то, наверное, стандарты изменились?...

Comment: Нет, вот как раз-таки компилятор и не пропустил такой вариант. Нужно i объявить до begin, тогда всё заработает, как и задумывалось :)

Comment: Ну, значит, в ideone какой-то не такой компилятор. Спасибо за замечание, сейчас исправлю ответ.

Comment: Это Вам спасибо! :)

Comment: @Stanislav Zinkin В вашем коде есть ещё одна существенная ошибка, которая не всегда проявляется.

Comment: @StanislavZinkin Такой синтаксис (объявление переменной в теле функции, после begin) - вполне легитимен для современных версий паскаля, давно не слежу за этой средой но в delphi xe10 это точно было доступно :)

Comment: @MBo А в чём ошибка, если не секрет?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Буду знать :)

Comment: @Stanislav Zinkin Индекс не инициирован. Если максимум в строке первым идёт, то там будет мусор.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi выдаёт предупреждение:

`[dcc32 Warning] ct3.dpr(23): W1019 For loop control variable must be simple local variable`

Ваш компилятор, вероятно, тоже предупреждал?

```
procedure findMaxAndIndex(const arr: arra; var max, index: integer);
var
  i: integer;   {!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!}
begin
  max := arr[1];
  index := 1;    {!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!}
  for i := 2 to Nmax do begin
    if max < arr[i] then begin
      max := arr[i];
      index := i;
    end;
  end;
end;
  ....
  { Находим максимальный элемент матрицы }

  {процедура ведь для этого уже есть}

  findMaxAndIndex(arrOfMax, maxofmatr, indofMax);
  { Выводим максимальный элемент }
  Writeln('Максимальный элемент матрицы: ', maxOfMatr);
  Writeln('Строка с максимумом: ', indOfMax);
  Readln;
```